# Definition of Identity element axiom

Tags: abstract-algebra

I saw the following definition for the Identity element axiom in Wikipedia

$$
\exists e\in A \ \ \forall a\in A \ \ e*a = a * e = a
$$

What I don't understand is why we need this: 
$$
a*e = e*a 
$$

Since this part is a case of the Commutativity axiom.

Please explain why we need this part or give a counter-example.

Thanks!

Comment: this axiom is independent from commutativity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commutativity only holds for *abelian* or *commutative* groups, which is not always the case (think about [$\mathfrak{S}_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) or [$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{K})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group)). Note also that if $e_l$ is left-identity element($\forall a\in A,e_l* a=a$) and if $e_r$ is right-identity element, then
$$e_l*e_r=e_l\text{ and }e_l*e_r=e_r$$ which implies $$e_l=e_r.$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post a reference to one of these? It's kinda hard googling from LaTex.

Comment: See: [$S_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) and [$\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb K)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group). Basically, permutations and matrix multiplication both generally form *non-abelian groups*; that is, groups where the group operation is **not** commutative.

Comment: @dod_moshe : I added links and a remark too !

Comment: I was convinced from S_n. Going to read about GLn now. Thank you!

Comment: @dod_moshe : You're welcome.